# Can React table render rows differently?

Tags: javascript, react-table

I have a table implemented in material table and it has served its purpose, unfortunately due to the poor performance issue where it re-renders every time there is a change in the state regardless of the states connection to the table itself.

I've opted to move to a different table and looking at React table as a possibility.

Can react table rows be customized that's not inline with the column data fully like the table below?

The parent has a different data compared to the sub-parent and the data in the sub-parent is different from its own parent (Which is the sub-parent).

[image: Table]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question.

Yes, react-table can certainly do these, you just need to conditionally render each row and table differently.